# Renaming project in solution and check it in to azure devops in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have a solution with 2 projects: Project1 and Project2. Both projects and the solution are currently in one TFS branch in Azure Devops. Project1 is a .net Core App while Project2 is a .Net Framework App. I want to migrate Project2 to .net Core and upload it to the repository, ideally using the same name, what's the best way to go about this? This is what I've tried so far:

1. Renaming the current .net framework Project2 to Project2NetFramework.
2. Renaming the folder where .net framework Project2 was stored
3. Creating a new .net core project and naming it Project2
4. Checking in Project2 to AzureDevops.

I get conflicts when checking in and when I check Azure Devops, Project2NetFramework is missing. Which steps do I have to follow to do this?

Comment: Hi @user1306470, I have updated my answer with more suggestions. Please check it.

Comment: Hi @user1306470, how are things going? Is the suggestion in my answer helpful to you? Please have a try with it. any progress, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[UPDATE]**

Follow your idea, you can try like as the steps below:

1. Before beginning the steps, make sure you have backup the .Net Framework project.
2. Delete the .Net Framework project from the solution.
3. Commit and push the changes to the repository on your TFS to check there is no any conflict or error can prevent the changes from being committed.
4. Create a .Net Core project in the solution.
5. Copy the required codes from the files in the backup .Net Framework project to the corresponding files in the .Net Core project.
6. Commit and push the changes to the repository on your TFS.

With this way, you can try to avoid the conflicts and confusions as much as possible.

---

You can reference to the following articles to try the migration from **.NET Framework** to **.NET Core**:

- [**Port from .NET Framework to .NET Core**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/)
- [**Migrating from .NET Framework to .NET Core: Tips and Tricks**](https://medium.com/outsystems-engineering/migrating-from-net-framework-to-net-core-tips-and-tricks-b8adb0fd56e5)
- [**How to Migrate from the .NET Framework to .NET 5 Controls**](https://www.grapecity.com/blogs/how-to-migrate-from-the-dot-net-framework-to-dot-net-5-controls)

Comment: Thank you man, it worked, but apart from following your steps I had to manually remove the projects from both my workspace and tfs